# Neo4j - Get Level2 or Level3 connections

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-cql

I'm developing a small connections structure to understand the concept of graph databases better, as well learn Neo4J

I have few users and the relationship between them is KNOWS as follows

[image]

I have the following cqls to create the nodes and relationships between then in Neo4j.

```
CREATE (user1:User {name:"User1",mail:"user1@test.com",mobile: 9000090001})
CREATE (user2:User {name:"User2",mail:"user2@test.com",mobile: 9000090002})
CREATE (user3:User {name:"User3",mail:"user3@test.com",mobile: 9000090003})
CREATE (user4:User {name:"User4",mail:"user4@test.com",mobile: 9000090004})
CREATE (user5:User {name:"User5",mail:"user5@test.com",mobile: 9000090005})
CREATE (user6:User {name:"User6",mail:"user6@test.com",mobile: 9000090006})
CREATE (user7:User {name:"User7",mail:"user7@test.com",mobile: 9000090007})
CREATE (user8:User {name:"User8",mail:"user8@test.com",mobile: 9000090008})
CREATE (user9:User {name:"User9",mail:"user9@test.com",mobile: 9000090009})

MATCH (user1:User), (user2:User) WHERE user1.mobile = 9000090001 AND user2.mobile = 9000090002 CREATE (user1)-[knows:KNOWS ]->(user2) RETURN user1, user2
MATCH (user1:User), (user2:User) WHERE user1.mobile = 9000090001 AND user2.mobile = 9000090003 CREATE (user1)-[knows:KNOWS ]->(user2) RETURN user1, user2
MATCH (user1:User), (user2:User) WHERE user1.mobile = 9000090002 AND user2.mobile = 9000090004 CREATE (user1)-[knows:KNOWS ]->(user2) RETURN user1, user2
MATCH (user1:User), (user2:User) WHERE user1.mobile = 9000090002 AND user2.mobile = 9000090005 CREATE (user1)-[knows:KNOWS ]->(user2) RETURN user1, user2
MATCH (user1:User), (user2:User) WHERE user1.mobile = 9000090003 AND user2.mobile = 9000090006 CREATE (user1)-[knows:KNOWS ]->(user2) RETURN user1, user2
MATCH (user1:User), (user2:User) WHERE user1.mobile = 9000090005 AND user2.mobile = 9000090007 CREATE (user1)-[knows:KNOWS ]->(user2) RETURN user1, user2
MATCH (user1:User), (user2:User) WHERE user1.mobile = 9000090005 AND user2.mobile = 9000090008 CREATE (user1)-[knows:KNOWS ]->(user2) RETURN user1, user2
MATCH (user1:User), (user2:User) WHERE user1.mobile = 9000090006 AND user2.mobile = 9000090009 CREATE (user1)-[knows:KNOWS ]->(user2) RETURN user1, user2
```

Now I want to fetch **level-2 or level-3 connections** for the given user.

For example:

```
If I ask for level-2 connections for User1 then I should get User4, User5, User6
If I ask for level-3 connections for User1 then I should get User7, User8, User9
```

I have the following CQL

```
START levelGraph=node(1)
MATCH path=(user1:User)-[knows:KNOWS*1..]->(user2:User)
WHERE user1.mobile = 9000090001
RETURN user1, user2, length(path) as downlevel
ORDER BY length(path) asc
```

this one is giving me all the direct or indirect connections that User1 has. Can anyone point me what should be my cql to fulfill this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify this

```
MATCH path=(user1:User)-[knows:KNOWS*1..]->(user2:User)
```

To get second level it should be like

```
MATCH path=(user1:User)-[knows:KNOWS*2..2]->(user2:User)
```

To get third level it should be like

```
 MATCH path=(user1:User)-[knows:KNOWS*3..3]->(user2:User)
```

Comment: thanks for the input, what if I have bi-directional relationships, what would be the cql change that I need to do?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand what you mean. Maybe something like MATCH path=(user1:User)-[knows:KNOWS*2..2]-(user2:User) will work for you

Comment: here posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596002/level-2-or-level-3-connections-when-we-have-bidirectional-relationship