# level-2 or level-3 connections when we have bidirectional relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-cql

Extention to this question [Neo4j - Get Level2 or Level3 connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569336/neo4j-get-level2-or-level3-connections)

I have the following relationship in Neo4j. Few nodes have bidirectional relationsips

[image]

I want to fetch the level-2 or level-3 connections for the given user.

I have the following CQL

```
START levelGraph=node(1)
MATCH path=(user1:User)-[knows:KNOWS*2..2]->(user2:User)
WHERE user1.mobile = 9000090001
RETURN user1, user2, length(path) as downlevel
ORDER BY length(path) asc
```

this one is giving me all the nodes who has relationship with User1 and its giving even User1 in output

I want to get all the unique level-2 or level-3 connection from the given user

### EDIT:

For User1 the connections at individual levels are as follows:

```
Level-1 => User2, User3, User4, User5, User6
Level-2 => User7, User8, User9, User10, User11, User12, User13, User14
```

So when I query to get Level2 connections I should get only these user7 to User14 distinctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the cypher query I have to fetch only level two connections:

CQL-1:

```
MATCH path=(user1:User)-[:KNOWS]->(:User)-[:KNOWS]->(user2:User) 
WHERE user1.mobile = 9000090001 AND user1 <> user2 AND NOT (user1)-[:KNOWS]->(user2)
RETURN distinct user2
ORDER BY user2.mobile
```

CQL-2

```
MATCH path=(user1:User)-[knows:KNOWS*2..2]->(user2:User)
WHERE user1.mobile = 9000090001 AND user1 <> user2 AND NOT (user1)-[:KNOWS]->(user2)
RETURN distinct user2
ORDER BY user2.mobile
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something along these lines return the nodes you expect?

```
MATCH path=(user1:User)-[knows:KNOWS*2..3]-(user2:User)
WHERE user1.name = 'User1'
AND user1 <> user2
RETURN user2, collect(length(path)) as downlevels, min(length(path)) as min_length
ORDER BY min_length
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, this does not give me expected result. I have updated my question, please can u have a look and post an update

Answer (score 0):

This query might suit your needs:

```
MATCH path=(user1:User)-[knows:KNOWS*2..3]->(user2:User) 
WHERE user1.mobile = 9000090001 AND user1 <> user2 
RETURN user1, COLLECT(DISTINCT user2), length(path) as downlevel 
ORDER BY downlevel;
```

It returns a row for each `downlevel`, and each row has a collection of the distinct nodes at that level. It also omits `user1` from the collections.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, this does not give me expected result. I have updated my question, please can u have a look and post an update